# VBA Issue with date format auto conversion

Tags: vba, excel, macros

A software exports data to xls. Software has date-time format "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss", but exported sheet, when opened in Excel, date is automatically changed to "m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss" only when day or month is <10, and it takes day as month and month as day. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What is it that should happen instead?  You can always use data>> from text and format that column as Text if you want to avoid the issue.  Unfortunately Excel really wants to mess with dates and unless you take care it will...

Answer (score 2):

Select cells or a range of your data in date format then look for the **Data Tools** section of the **Data** menu tab. Choose **Text to Columns**, click **Next**  then click **Next** again. Mark **Date** in the option button of column data format and choose **DMY**, then click **Finish**.